# To count the number of 1's in a row in python

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a dataframe with column names ranging from P1 to P10

```
  p1 p2 p3  p4  p5 
    0   0  0  1    1
    0   0  0  0    0
    1   1  1  1    1

the total number of 1 has to be displayed at the end of the row 
example : first row = 2 
second row = 0
third row = 5
```

Comment: `df.eq(1).sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 6):

Use if always `1` and `0` values in all columns only `sum`:

```
 df['new'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

If possible another values then first compare for boolean mask and then count `True`s by `sum`:

```
 df['new'] = df.eq(1).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *Numpy* functions.

In the case like yours (only *1* and *0*), you can use:

```
df['sum'] = np.count_nonzero(df, axis=1)
```

But if you have also other numbers, use:

```
df['sum'] = np.count_nonzero(df == 1, axis=1)
```